# Rename files reading old file name and new file name from a txt file (bash)

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

I need to rename a bunch of files in a directory:

```
2016001.fas
2016002.fas
2016003.fas
...
```

Reading through a .txt that has the actual and the new filename tab separated:

```
2016001 L.innocua001
2016002 L.innocua002
2016003 L.monocytogenes001
...
```

Maybe using a one line for loop or a pipe in bash.

As a note, I can also have the list with actual and new filename in .csv or comma separated .txt format if needed. I appreciate the help given.

Comment: In the future, be sure to include your best attempt to solve your problem. We're not here to write code for you. Good solutions below. Good luck.

Comment: Again in the future, such questions are more appropriate to the [su] site. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
xargs -a renames.txt -n 2 sh -c 'echo mv -- "$1.fas" "$2.fas"' _
```

- `xargs -a renames.txt`: process content of the `renames.txt` as arguments to a command.
- `-n 2`: pick 2 arguments at a time.
- `sh -c`: command is to run an inline shell
- The inline shell `'echo mv -- "$1.fas" "$2.fas"'`: Performs the actual rename using arguments 1 and 2 provided by xargs.

```sh
# remove echo when output matches the intent
echo mv -- "$1.fas" "$2.fas"
```

Method using a shell only to read `renames.txt` and execute the renames:

```sh
while read -r a b; do
  # Remove echo if satisfied by the output
  echo mv -- "$a.fas" "$b.fas"
done <renames.txt
```

Alternate method with awk to transform the `renames.txt` file into a shell script with the rename commands:

```sh
awk '{print "mv -- "$1".fas "$2".fas"}' renames.txt
```

Once satisfied by the output of awk above; save to a shell script file, or pipe directly to sh.

Comment: Hi Léa, I tried the first two approaches but I keep getting the new files like this: `'L.innocua01'$'\r'.fas'` , do you know why this happens? The name changed successfully but it's adding the other unwanted characters.

Comment: `dos2unix renames.txt` should fix your problem, then rerun your script. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after converting the file, and sorry for not posting a code, I'm running a bioinformatic program and needed to change the filenames for convention, I know the basics in bash but not coding. Limited knowledge in the packages available.